# Does using $routeProvider save network bandwidth?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, node.js, http

Consider this `$routeProvider` config for `navbar`  **and assume no caching**

```
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
    });
```

I read online that one of the advantage of Single Page Application is network bandwidth since it does not need to transfer html tags every time user switch pages.

However, when we have above situation where `navbar` has home, about, contact that are routed to separate pages, wouldn't it have to transfer html tags every time?

Does it still save up the network bandwidth by eliminating html tag transfer?

Answer (score 1):

You could say it does, but in the same breath, it doesn't. If you really need to save network bandwidth, I know of [this website](http://codetunnel.net/) but I don't know jQuery well enough to understand what it is doing so I can't do anything there to help you. That website only has one page, but the nav menu hides and shows div's so you get that sort of "multi-page" website only with one page. Hopefully, I answered your question and gave you something you can work off of. I did pull the jQuery off the site, but I can't get it to work, so maybe you can figure it out and PM me what happened.

**EDIT:**
I figured out the jQuery so i will put my full codepen below ;).

```js
$(function(){
    $("#nav-home").click(function(){
     $("#home").show();
     $("#projects").hide();
     $("#contact").hide();

     $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

     $("#nav-home").addClass("selected");
    });

    $("#nav-projects").click(function(){
     $("#home").hide();
     $("#projects").show();
     $("#contact").hide();

     $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

     $("#nav-projects").addClass("selected");
    });

    $("#nav-contact").click(function(){
     $("#home").hide();
     $("#projects").hide();
     $("#contact").show();

     $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

     $("#nav-contact").addClass("selected");
    });
   });
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 4em
}

#navbar {
                    height:100%;
                    width: 14em;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }

                #navbar h1 {
                    margin-top: 1em;
                    margin-bottom: 2em;
                    display: block;
                }

                #navbar ul li {
                    display: list-item;
                    margin: 0.2em 0em;
                }

                #navbar ul {
                    margin: 1.4em;
                    display: block;
                }

                #page {
                    padding-top: 0;
                    padding-left: 16.5em;
                }
#navbar {
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                height: 3em;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-color: #282726;
                box-shadow: inset -1em 0 2em rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                color: #FFFFFF;
                text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                font-size: 110%;
            }

            #navbar h1 {
                font-size: 2em;
                color: #0077FF;
                margin: 0.2em;
                display: inline;
            }

            #navbar ul {
                list-style: none;
                font-size: 1.4em;
                text-align: left;
                margin: 0.6em;
                display: inline;
            }

            #navbar ul li {
                margin: 0.2em;
                display: inline;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            #navbar ul li:hover,#navbar ul li.selected {
                color: #0077FF;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
<h1>Sample Page</h1>
<ul>
<li id="nav-home" class="selected">-&nbsp;Home</li>
<li id="nav-projects">-&nbsp;Projects</li>
<li id="nav-contact">-&nbsp;Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="home">Home Items Here</div>

<div id="projects" style="display: none;">Project List Here</div>

<div id="contact" style="display: none;">Contact Me here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using `$routeProvider` you are still maintaining the single page application. Its just changing the content of web page but not refreshing the whole page again.

```
  - script.js             <!-- stores all our angular code -->
- index.html            <!-- main layout -->
- pages                 <!-- the pages that will be injected into the main layout -->
----- home.html
----- about.html
----- contact.html
```

In the above code structure only the pages which are injected to index.html will get change by using `$routeprovider` not the index.html. Hence while switching pages will be fetched from client side not from the server side.